# $1+n^2x^2\geqslant 2nx$

Tags: calculus

[image]

How did they get $1+n^2x^2\geqslant 2nx$? Did they use partial derivatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $1+n^2x^2-2nx={(1-nx)}^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$F:X\mapsto \frac{X}{1+X^2} $$ defined for $X\ge 0$ attains its maximum when $X=1$,  because

$$F'(X)=\frac {1-X^2}{(1+X^2)^2} $$thus
the function $f_n $ attains its maximum when $x=1/n $.

$$0\le f (x)\le f_n (1/n)=1/2$$

Answer (score 5):

$$0 \le (nx-1)^2 = n^2x^2 - 2nx + 1$$

Can you take it from there?  (There's really not much left to do.)

Answer (score 2):

It's the AM/GM inequality: $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$.